# Finding the intersection of a line with a polygon

Tags: android, kotlin, geospatial, turfjs

I am trying to find the intersection of a line represented by two geographical coordinates and a polygon represented by three or more geographical coordinates.
My goal is to find the closest point to the first coordinate on any of the polygon's boundary lines and the line described by the first two coordinates.

I am assuming that the polygon is a simple closed polygon (i.e. rectangle).

[image]

In this case the algorithm would return the intersection point marked in red (closer to the first coordinate).

I am using Kotlin for android.

I was trying to use Turf for Java but was not able to find the functions to do that.

Comment: Your goal has nothing to do with the intersection of the line and the polygon (what would be the role of the second point of the line?). Please clarify your problem (possibly with a sketch) so that we can help you.

Comment: The answer is probably to use JTS (org.locationtech.jts.*)

Comment: Added a diagram

Comment: @Cloverleaf Added a diagram which would hopefully help explain the problem

Comment: Thanks for the diagram. But are you aware that the red point is generally **not** the closest blue point to 1, so it does **not** fulfill your stated goal (unless the green line happens to be perpendicular to the rightmost blue line)? The closest point to 1 on the polygon is the intersection of the perpendicular from 1 to the rightmost blue line. So again: What do you want to calculate? The red point or the blue point with the smallest distance to 1 (then you don't need 2 at all)?

Comment: I am trying to find the red point. It is the closest point to 1 on the green line described by points 1 and 2 that intersects the circumference of the blue polygon

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is actually a library for this problem, but why load thousends of code lines when you can do it yourself with 10 or 20 lines of code?

The coordinates of the points must be given in degrees (i.e. 8°30'00" -> 8.5) and have negative signs for the southern and western hemisphere respectively. Then you can find the coordinates of the red point you are looking for with the following algorithm:

1. For **each** blue line segment (there are 6 of them in your drawing), you have to use formula 1 (see below) to calculate whether the blue line segment intersects the green line at all, and if so, you have to calculate the coordinates of the intersection point. In your example, you will find two such intersection points.
2. For **each** intersection point that you have found in step 1), you must calculate the distance squared to point 1 using formula 2. The intersection point from 1) with the **smallest** distance squared is the red point you are looking for.

**Formula 1:**
If you are familiar with math, you can find everything you need [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#Given_two_points_on_each_line_segment) (or look for "intersection of two line segment" on the Internet). If not, I can explain it to you step by step. I would then need to know: Is the red point **guaranteed** to be between 1 and 2, or could 1 and 2 also be on the same side of the polygon? Is the green straight line **guaranteed** to hit the blue polygon?

**Formula 2:**
If (P.x, P.y) is an intersection point from 1), it has the distance squared

```
(P.x - 1.x) * (P.x - 1.x) + (P.y - 1.y) * (P.y - 1.y)
```

from 1 = (1.x, 1.y).

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, I will give it a try. 
Will this work well on geo locations? since we are talking on an imperfect sphere I am not sure that this solution will work, and if it will what will be it's inaccuracies.

Comment: The formulas given are only exact valid in the ideal case of 2-dimensional Euclidean geometry (i.e. flat earth without elevations). If your blue polygon is very large (about >500km), you would have to use spherical geometry and replace lines with great circles (like the equator), see for example omnicalculator.com/math/great-circle). For smaller polygons, I estimate that the deviations from the plane case are < 1m, about the accuracy with which you can measure the corners of the polygon.